# What is std::variant in Java

Tags: java

I am wondering what the closest thing to std::variant would be. I know Object exists, but that's not an option for me, I want to be able to restrict what I am dealing with.

An example of what I want to achieve with it is

```
static String helper(Object o) {
    switch (o.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
        case "String": 
            return String.format("String %s", o); 
        case "Integer": 
            return String.format("Integer %d", o); 
        default: 
            return String.format("Object %s", o);
    }
}
```

But as mentioned, I would like to be able to restrict what the input might be.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but you should use `instanceof` here

Comment: Java is not C++, you should not expect to find direct equivalents for everything. Why isn't this just three overloaded methods?

Comment: Would creating your own generic class with bounded type parameters be a viable solution? Check the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Comment: Fundamentally, Java does NOT have union types. `std::variant` is used for the *type-safe union*, but Java... Well, there is *Vavr* Java library for the *Either* type in functional languages, but it is a little cumbersome for those who do not have functional language background: https://docs.vavr.io/#_either

Comment: In natural Java, what you have there is `Object`.  It's the easiest and most succinct.  You might consider defining your own type, `StringOrNumber` or something, but that would depend on details you haven't given us.

Comment: @Naetmul This is perfect, thanks! Reminds me of OCaml, I love it!